# How to make a non blurry text-shadow from the center?

Tags: css

how do you make a text shadow which doesn't have a blurry effect like shown here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lim8.png)

Comment: oh come on. Instead of downvoting my question, can't you just tell me if it's possible or not? I wasted enough time searching for answers and this is my last chance.

Comment: The [general guideline for asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good place to start on answering why you got downvoted. You tend to get a better response if you show what you have tried first. And finally [this](https://designshack.net/articles/css/12-fun-css-text-shadows-you-can-copy-and-paste/) took me 1min to google first.

Comment: it isn't what I was looking for. I wanted to know if there's a possibilty to place the text-shadow in the centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-stroke` is the CSS property you're looking for, but if you need support for IE/Edge, you'd need to use `text-shadow` in order to fake it.

Mind tough, that with the latter you'll have to play around with the multiple shadows to achieve the desired thicknes, and the multiple values can get rather lengthy. (You can see at the corners of the letters that some more multiple values would be needed to make it seem smooth, and even more values if you wanted to have more than 2px...)

```css
span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #f00;
}

.stroked {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px black;
  text-stroke: 3px black;
}

.outlined {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #000,
  -2px -2px 0 #000,
  2px -2px 0 #000,
  -2px 2px 0 #000,
  0px 2px 0 #000,
  2px 0px 0 #000,
  0px -2px 0 #000,
  -2px 0px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<span class="stroked">text-stroke</span><br>
<span class="outlined">text-shadow</span>
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you so much!

Comment: Someone else obviously didn't think so and downvoted... ;) Feel free to upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted as you see fit!

Comment: I can't upvote answers :(